# Redirect all outbound UDP DNS request to a localhost DNS server

Tags: linux, networking, iptables

I am trying to redirect all outbound DNS requests (made from my LAN) to a tunnel running on localhost listening for UDP on 127.0.0.1:5353.

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j DNAT --to 127.0.0.1:5353
```

Testing it with

```
nc -u -l -p 5353
```

and

```
nc -u 127.0.0.1 53
```

is fine, and the UDP session is working, but when I try it with:

```
nc -u 8.8.8.8 53
```

`nc` listening can receive the traffic, but the reply fails with:

> sent 2, rcvd 2 : Connection refused

while

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j DNAT --to 192.168.1.108:5353
```

works correctly, and the devices running on the same WiFi network can receive the replies successfully.

**Edit:** DNS queries made with TCP are managed separately, there is no need to consider it.

Comment: Is your `named` listening to requests on `127.0.0.1:5353`?

Comment: It is a proxy tunnel that will relay udp traffic, which can listen on other ports as well(I prefer to listen to a port >= 1024).

Comment: There is no proxy or tunnel in your question but I considered that was unimportant to answer it, but it is essential to clarify what interface and port your `named` is listening to.  Failure to provide that will prevent you from getting the answer you need.

Comment: add please `netstat -an | grep 53` output and specify which daemon are you using to listen on port 5353

Comment: Is there any special design required for dealing with forwarded UDP traffic? It is an non-mainstream proxy, called v2ray, which can tunnel internet traffic through a encrypted tunnel. It's role and behavior is similar to DNSCrypt. I asked it to tunnel the traffic to remote. There is no special code in v2ray for dealing with forwarded traffic.

Comment: It seems that pdnsd can reply the DNS traffic without problem, is there any special design in its code?

Comment: I can just let request go through pdnsd to avoid this problem, but is there a solution for this?

Comment: I did more research and found that kernel think traffic from 127.0.0.1 are Martian Packets so they are not going to be routed.

Comment: Inferred from pdnsd's source, I seems that it it mandatory for program to support redirected udp traffic in order to send reply packet in a correct way.

Comment: In one rule you redirect traffic to localhost, while you redirect it to the actual local IP address in the other, you test and redirect with ports 53 and 5353.  So we are all wondering what your DNS server is listening to and you don't respond.  Until you do, don't expect a good answer.

Comment: $ netstat -an | grep 53
tcp6       0      0 :::5353                :::*                   LISTEN
udp6       0      0 :::5353                :::*                   CLOSE

Comment: The martian packets are a tell the tunnel configuration is not finished - you are missing a rp_filter = 0; as for the DNS proxy, it should be bound only to 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 3):

For redirecting DNS UDP based requests, if your DNS daemon/proxy is listening in port 5353/UDP, you have to do:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -s 192.168.1.0/24 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:5353
```

The source has to be the internal netblock/network(s) used as we do not need loops (i.e. we still may need to do DNS requests to the outside).

If routing for a internal network in a multi homed machine, you can also apply the interface, not needing the source network.

```
iptables -i eth0 -t nat -A PREROUTING  -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:5353
```

You can also do it in port 53 as long as you blacklist the destination as in:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING  ! -d 127.0.0.1/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:53
```

The OUTPUT queue may work in local tests, however for remote machines and the current config, it is advisable to use the PREROUTING queue.

Comment: Why was this answer downvoted? What's wrong with it, if anything? (I'm looking for a similar solution.)

Comment: Because in the particular solution of routing through layer 7, eg a proxy, jt is indeed output; if routing via tcp/ip it is prerouting. This is a particular case of a very interesting configuration; ask yourself a question and direct me to it here. I may also had the full "problem" as a question answered by myself in my profile of my setup.

Comment: (it was downvoted, but then corrected much later on)